# Is Norway significantly more expensive than other European destinations?

Tags: budget, norway

As a budget traveller, i.e. staying in hostels, using public transport, self catering where possible, is Norway significantly more expensive than say Germany or France? If so what's the best way to minimize the cost?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a generally accepted fact that the Scandinavian countries are the most expensive places to travel. But personally, having travelled a lot within Europe and within Scandinavia, I don't think it's SO much more expensive in comparison to the rest of Europe.

Where prices differ is generally when it comes to alcohol (much more expensive), junk food/convenience food and eating out. If you're willing to buy your own food (and eat a lot of veg and not so much meat) and stay in the most basic hostels then the price difference is negligible. Public transport is in some places cheaper than in other parts of Europe.

But at the same time remember that you can expect to be paying 10kr ($1.8) for a can of coke. A beer can be anywhere upwards of 50kr, often as high as 80-90kr. The tap water is great though, so drinking should not be a problem.

If you're really careful you can probably get by on 6-700kr per day. Don't buy any fast food or junk food, this will really hit you in the wallet.

e: A slightly funny way of measuring relative expensiveness is the Big Mac Index: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Mac_Index

This is the Norwegian hostelling international website, membership is very much worth it in my experience: http://www.hihostels.no/no/ You can get accomodation for as cheap as 220/night even in summer if you're lucky.

Comment: Just nitpicking regarding your two first paragraphs: No, whether Norway is _more expensive than other European countries_ does NOT depend on the asker's country or exchange rate. Great info otherwise :-)

Comment: +1 for the alcohol example. I was only in Oslo ten years ago and I found prices increased along this scale at that time: Germany < Denmark < Sweden < Norway. I decided I couldn't afford to travel beyond Oslo on my budget. Your hostel and per-day prices make Norway seem more expensive than Australia which is definitely outside my budget these days and that's where I'm from (-:

Answer (score 22):

victoriah wrote in her answer:

> It's a generally accepted fact that the Scandinavian countries are the
>   most expensive places to travel. But personally, having travelled a
>   lot within Europe and within Scandinavia, I don't think it's SO much
>   more expensive in comparison to the rest of Europe.

I'm from Finland—another Nordic country generally considered expensive—and my understanding (anecdotal, from friends and colleagues who have visited or lived in Norway) is that Norway is significantly more expensive *than Finland*.

So the short answer is: **Yes**, Norway most certainly is significantly more expensive than European destinations in general. It resembles Switzerland in this regard.
<sup>Which is *not* to say that you shouldn't visit! :-)</sup>

On the other hand, if you have the possibility to work there, it's a great place to earn money. :-)

Some examples: A [beer in a bar](http://www.pintprice.com/region.php?/Norway/EUR.htm) in Oslo can set you back as much as 10 € (~80kr). In Helsinki 4-6 € is normal and considered expensive by most foreigners. Price for a dorm bed in an Oslo hostel [seems](http://www.hostelworld.com/findabed.php/ChosenCity.Oslo/ChosenCountry.Norway) to range from 29 to 51 € (!), while in countries like Germany or France I've generally paid around 15-25 €.

In any case, I guess victoriah is right in that if you're careful you can keep your costs relatively low even in Norway. One obvious way to save heaps would be to pay nothing for accommodation, through [CouchSurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org/) or a similar service, if that's your cup of tea. Norway has a high density of hospitable people opening their homes to strangers. One British CS guest of mine, for example, had great experiences in Norway and said it was much easier to find a host there compared e.g. to Baltics.

**Edit**: I just noticed that the [Norway guide on Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Norway) has a good section on [costs](http://wikitravel.org/en/Norway#Costs). Quoting a little bit:

> Norway is an expensive country. While it is possible to travel in
>   Norway on a limited budget, some care must be taken. Because labour is
>   costly, anything that can be seen as a "service" will in general be
>   more expensive than you expect. Travel costs can also be a killer,
>   because the country is large and distances long, so a rail or air pass
>   can save you a lot of money.
>
> As rules of thumb, **subsisting on under
>   500 kr/day (~65 €) will be difficult** even if you stay in hostels and
>   self-cater, with 1000 kr/day allowing a more comfortable mid-range
>   lifestyle and over 2000 kr/day needed for good hotels and restaurants.

### Update: Here are some actual statistics

(Which happen to support my anecdotal knowledge perfectly.)

A recent (2012) [Eurostat study](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/ITY_PUBLIC/2-22062012-AP/EN/2-22062012-AP-EN.PDF) on prices of goods and services found that if EU zone average price level is described with 100, the **most expensive countries in Europe are**:

1. Switzerland 162 (i.e., prices are 162% of the EU27 average)
2. **Norway 151**
3. Denmark 142 (the most expensive EU country)
4. Sweden 128
5. Finland 125 (the most expensive eurozone country)
6. Luxembourg 122
7. Ireland 117

Looking at prices of *alcoholic beverages & tobacco* only, Norway is far and away above everyone else at 250 (followed by Iceland 155, UK 147, Sweden 145). Also for *food & non-alcoholic beverages* Norway is the most expensive: Norway 164, Switzerland 156, Denmark 136, Sweden 120. The same goes for *restaurants & hotels*: Norway 184, Swizerland 157, Denmark 154, Sweden 147. In other words, **in things most relevant to a traveller, Norway is *the* most expensive country in Europe**.

The cheapest European countries included in this study were Macedonia (45), Albania (51), Bulgaria (51), Serbia (57), and Bosnia and Herzegovina (57), with Bulgaria (51) and Romania (60) being the cheapest EU countries.

Sources:

- Eurostat: [Price levels varied in 2011 from 51% of the EU27
  average in Bulgaria to 142% in Denmark](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/ITY_PUBLIC/2-22062012-AP/EN/2-22062012-AP-EN.PDF) (PDF)
- HS: [Eurostat: Suomi kallein euromaa](http://www.hs.fi/talous/Eurostat+Suomi+kallein+euromaa/a1305578331282)

Comment: My latest "anecdote" came today from a workmate who just got back from 1-week holiday in Norway. He liked it, but considered the country "absurdly" expensive, with many things costing 1.5 times what they are in Finland.

Comment: Btw, if anyone wonders *why* Norway is even more expensive than its Nordic neighbours, well, largely it stems from the fact that it is an [oil-rich](http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/nationworld/2004024446_norway20.html) country, with [one of the biggest reserves](http://www.nationmaster.com/graph/ene_oil_res_percap-energy-oil-reserves-per-capita) per capita.

Comment: Related travel story by Seth Kugel (aka [@frugaltraveler](https://twitter.com/frugaltraveler)): [A $100 Weekend in Oslo](http://frugaltraveler.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/06/26/a-100-weekend-in-oslo/). The closing remark was funny.

Comment: Good background reading on Norwegian economy: [The Economist: The rich cousin](http://www.economist.com/news/special-report/21570842-oil-makes-norway-different-rest-region-only-up-point-rich)

Answer (score 8):

With Norway, it is easier to point out what is *cheap* rather than what is *expensive*.

In contrast to iHaveacomputer's answer, I find all kinds of fruit and vegetables cheap. That is because the fruit and vegetables are subsidized, and would otherwise cost a fortune.

[First Price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Price) is a low cost brand that provides cheaper alternatives, sometimes equal in quality to its competitors. First Price products can be found at Kiwi or Meny (both grocery stores) and probably some other stores.

Landlord is a brand similar to First Price, but I only remember seeing their products at Rema 1000 (another grocery store).

Answer (score 7):

I've never been to Norway, but I lived with a norweigan guy in Ireland for a year. Ireland is/was more expensive that most the rest of europe. He said that coming from Norway was great cause Ireland was cheaper than home, an experience not many visitors can say!

I've heard anecdotially that Norway is more expensive that the rest of europe.

Comment: Sure, but i that imho refers more to the costs of living - rent, power, gas, heating or things like new cars, home electronics etc. which is way more expensive because of the high taxes in Norway - but this is stuff that wont affect most travelers much who use public transport and stay in hostels. :)

Comment: It will affect the things you need to buy though. I found fast food more expensive and lower quality. Oslo kebabs were the worst I've had and kebabs are standard hot food for budget travellers who don't do their own cooking and are not vegetarians (-; (Greek gyros are the best and German döner are next best)

Comment: @ihaveacomputer Those costs will affect hostel owners!

Comment: FTR this Norwegian guy said that lots of things that would affect travelers are more expensive in Norway, e.g. drinks in a bar are more expensive in Norway.

Answer (score 4):

For you as a Backpacker, Norway will be on pretty much the same level as for example Germany, France or Sweden, but slightly more expensive than eastern Europe. The Hostel rates should be about the same.

However some things are more expensive in Norway: Beer and Alcohol - i went out on a saturday with something equal to 20 Euro, and i got 2cl of whisky and some change for it...
Tropical fruits like Bananas, Oranges and everything that wont grow in cold climate costs more, especially in all the small villages up north.

Domestic flights are also way more expensive (possibly because there is not much demand for it because few people live up there; and they only use small planes), and im not aware of any budget airline. Take the train or bus instead, unless you are in a hurry.

Comment: Are you sure? I found Germany to be cheap for western Europe and Eastern Europe where I am now in an utterly different ballpark. Right now I'm living on 75 Romanian Lei per day, more extravagant than some of my friends here but I know it's at the extreme end for users of this site. That's about 135 NOK or 17.50 Euro. I doubt I could get anywhere near that in Norway no matter how extreme my budget tactics.

Comment: I was backpacking from Germany up to Sweden and Norway in 2006. As far as i remember the prices for hostels where all around the 20 Euro/night mark at this time. Dresden, Germany was imho the cheapest with 16, and in stockholm 22 or 24 as far as i remember. 
East Germany might still be a bit cheaper than West Germany (Frankfurt, Munich or Cologne).

Comment: There's more to travel than youth hostels.  As a simple example, a doner kebab in Germany costs around 3 euros, while one in Oslo is 60 kr plus, or around 8 euros.  That's a 250% difference in what's basically the cheapest hot take-away meal you can buy!